# Oracle: How much averaged per month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Orders` with `order_date` and `order_total`. Is it possible to find out how much was averaged ordered per month?

```
=== ORDER_DATE === ORDER_TOTAL
--- 7-JAN-10   --- 5271
--- 12-JAN-10  --- 3646
--- 15-JAN-10  --- 310
--- 5-FEB-10   --- 71173
--- 12-FEB-10  --- 45175
--- 25-FEB-10  --- 126
```

In this case it would be:

```
JAN - 3075.66667 // calculation: (5271 + 3646 + 310) / 3
FEB - 38824.6667 // calculation: (71173 + 45175 + 126) / 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to reduce each date to its month. The `TRUNC()` function below will return the first day of the month for each date. AVG() is an aggregate function, so you'll want to `GROUP BY` the month.

```
SELECT TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') AS order_month, AVG(order_total) AS order_avg
  FROM orders
 GROUP BY TRUNC(order_date, 'MM')
```

Another way to accomplish this with analytic/window functions (this way you can return all the order data along with the average per month) would be as follows:

```
SELECT order_date, order_total, AVG(order_total) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(order_date, 'MM'))
  FROM orders
```

The OP asked the following:

> In the order order_month column I get something like 01-JAN-10 or
>   01-FEB-10. Is it also possible, to change it to FEB-10? Just without
>   the day.

I had suggested using `TO_CHAR()` with a mask of 'MON-YY' in this case but this meant that he could no longer sort properly on that column since it was now a string and not a date. One way to handle this would be as follows:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(order_month, 'MON-YY'), order_avg
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') AS order_month, AVG(order_total) AS order_avg
      FROM orders
     GROUP BY TRUNC(order_date, 'MM')
     ORDER BY order_month
 )
```

Comment: In the order `order_month` column I get something like `01-JAN-10` or `01-FEB-10`. Is it also possible, to change it to `FEB-10`? Just without the day.

Comment: Yes, use `TO_CHAR(order_date, 'MON-YY')` rather than `TRUNC(order_date, 'MM')` in both the `SELECT` columns and the `GROUP BY`. Pick a character mask you like and roll with it. If you have a lot of records in your table it might be worthwhile to put a function index on `order_date`.

Comment: Oh, this way I can't use `order by order_month` anymore. Maybe because it's just a String now, not a date anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can do a subquery in that case, formatting the date returned, or you can return both calculated columns grouping by both.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible.

you write a query, use `AVG` and finally `GROUP BY` the month

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select trunc(order_date, 'MONTH') as start_of_month, avg(order_total)
from orders
group by 1;
```

(No, I did not test it.)

Comment: I don't think that will work in all flavors of Oracle - I just tried it in 10g and no go.

Answer (score 0):

@ Evgeni,David

```
select trunc( to_date('5-FEB-10','dd-MON-YY'),'MON') from dual;
```

returns 01-02-2010 not FEB.

Instead use

```
select to_char(order_date,'MON-YY') as order_month, avg(order_total) 
from orders group by to_char(order_date,'MON-YY')
order by order_month;
```

tested by me. Order by is working perfectly as well.

Comment: `ORDER BY` won't work here when the dates are spread out over years. More to the point, it won't even work for months as e.g. 'DEC-11' comes before 'NOV-11' when sorting by CHAR values. I just tried this on a table in my DB and got results in this order: `'DEC-02', 'JUL-10', 'SEP-00'`